# AppleScript for folder action stops working after I make a minor change

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a folder action that runs an AppleScript. All it does is just grab the files in a folder and "embeds" the file in an email (i.e. embedding images inline in an email vs as an "attachment").

I've used it successfully for years and through different macOS versions (I'm currently still on Mojave).

But I tried to change the sent-to email address today, and the script stopped working. Now it'll open a new email. fill in the subject and recipient, but stops there.
It still doesn't work after I revert the change. I had to restore the applescript file from a backup to get it to work again.

Does anyone know why it would do this and how I can fix it?

Here's the script:

```applescript
on adding folder items to thisFolder after receiving theseItems
    tell application "Mail" to activate
    repeat with thisItem in theseItems
        tell application "Finder" to set thisName to name of thisItem
        tell application "Mail"
            set theMessageBody to ""
            set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:thisName, content:theMessageBody}
            tell theMessage
                make new to recipient with properties {name:"xyz", address:"xyz@domain.com"}
                make new attachment with properties {file name:thisItem} at after the last word of the last paragraph
                delay 1
                send theMessage
            end tell
        end tell
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

Comment: Actually `tell theMessage` followed by `send theMessage` is wrong (double reference). Delete `theMessage` after `send`

Comment: Thanks, I tried fixing it, but then the same problem occurs. I don't know why that script is so "fragile" that as soon as I change *anything*, it stops working, **even if I change the edit back. I actually have to revert the entire file from a Time Machine backup for it to work again.